# How to manage deep linking URL when app not install on my iphone?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, deep-linking

I am trying to work with **deep linking** in my project, the big issue is when the app is install on my device and URL redirect on my device & app is open, but when app is not installed on my device , the URL was not redirect in safari browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are confusing between `deep link` and `universal link`. `URL Schemes Deep Linking` does not allow to open Safari browser if the link is not available. Trying to use this method `canOpenURL(_:)`. If it returns false, you can open another URL manually. Or just using `Universal Link` instead.

Comment: Can you please provide steps to implement in Xcode of universal link?

Comment: I used to use Firebase Dynamic Link, [check this guide line](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)

Comment: Hello, i have one issue, if app is install in my device so it is redirecting on apple store then open, i want to open app page directly when click on URL

Comment: I didn't get it. You want to open an URL instead of open the app when tapping on 
 the dynamic link, don't you?

Comment: Do you forget to add `Associated Domains` entitlements?

Comment: Whan the app is not install on my iphone, i will redirect to the apple store, app install and when i open it, how to get URL data ?